# string cannot be converted to ArrayList<String> when getting as request.getParameter(" ")

Tags: java, string, list, jsp, arraylist

Getting List values in jsp as request.getParameter("") from another jsp

a.jsp

```
List<String> abc = 
 (ArrayList<String>)request.getAttribute("studentsrollno");// got 
  studentsrollno from servlet by request.setAttribute();

   <form action="b.jsp" method="post">
       <input type="hidden" name="rollno" value="<%=abc%>"/>

            <input type="submit">
   </form>
```

b.jsp

```
         <%
   List<String> a2 = (ArrayList<String>) request.getParameter("rollno");// 
 getting error string cannot be converted to ArrayList<String> // How can I 
 display data rollno here ?

  // Iterator<String> itr = a2.iterator();

             %>
```

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the values as an array:

```
String[] vals = request.getParameterValues("rollno");
```

The values should be emitted as separate form parameters:

```
<c:foreach items="${abc}" var="item">
    <input type="hidden" name="rollno" value="${fn:escapeXml(item)}" />
</c:foreach>
```

Comment: @Tom You should never use scriptlets, so skip that part and go straight to using JSTL.